# FindFirstChangeNotification is notifying about changes twice

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to monitor a folder in my file system. Let say I want to monitor the folder: C:\MyNewFolder

I have this code to do it:

```
HANDLE  ChangeHandle=FindFirstChangeNotification(_T("C:\\\MyNewFolder"),FALSE,FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);
for(;;)
{
    DWORD Wait=WaitForSingleObject(ChangeHandle,INFINITE);
    if (Wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,_T("Change"),_T("Change"),MB_OK);
        FindNextChangeNotification(ChangeHandle);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to have a messagebox that notifying me about any file change in my folder. That code works fine but I have one problem. The problem is that I got 2 notification for each change. What is the problem with my code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  A change to a file usually involves a change to the file data as well as a change to the directory entry.  Metadata properties like the file length and the last write date are stored there.  So you'll get a notification for both.  ReadDirectoryChangesW() doesn't otherwise distinguish between the two.

This is not different from a process making multiple changes to the same file.  Be sure to be able to handle both conditions.  This usually involves a timer so you don't go overboard with the number of operations you perform on a notification.  Such a timer is also often required because the process that is changing the file still has a lock on it that prevents you from doing anything with the file.  Until the process closes the file, an indeterminate amount of time later.

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably seeing is multiple changes to the one file (e.g. a file being created, and then written to, or a file being written to multiple times, etc). Unfortunately `FindFirstChangeNotification` doesn't tell you what has actually happened.

You're better off using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` for file notification as it will actually tell you **what** has changed.