# WaitForSingleObject with FindFirstChangeNotification not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, winapi

I have to find out if there is a new file in a directory on Windows. Following this MSDN example ([Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications)), I came up with the following test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string FindNewFile(std::vector<std::string>& vsNewFileList, std::vector<std::string>& vsOldFileList)
{
    std::string sNewFileName;
    int nScore = 0;
    for (auto& newFile : vsNewFileList)
    {
        nScore = 0;
        for (auto& oldFile : vsOldFileList)
            if(!newFile.compare(oldFile))
                nScore++;
        if (nScore!=1)
        {
            sNewFileName = newFile;
            break;
        }
    }
    return sNewFileName;
}

void GetCurrentFilesInDir(std::string sDir, std::vector<std::string>& vsFileList)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    sDir += "\\*";
    std::wstring wStr = std::wstring(sDir.begin(), sDir.end());
    LPCWSTR lpcwsDir = (LPCWSTR)wStr.c_str();
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(lpcwsDir, &ffd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Nope\n";
        return;
    }
    vsFileList.clear();
    do
    {
        int nSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ffd.cFileName, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        char* pcStr = new char[nSize];
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ffd.cFileName, -1, pcStr, nSize, 0, 0);
        //std::cout << pcStr << "\n";
        vsFileList.push_back(std::string(pcStr));
        delete[] pcStr;
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
 }

int main()
{
    // watch the foo directory for new files
    std::string sDir = "C:\\foo";

    std::vector<std::string> vsOldFileList, vsNewFileList;
    GetCurrentFilesInDir(sDir, vsOldFileList);
    std::wstring wStr = std::wstring(sDir.begin(), sDir.end());
    LPCWSTR lpcwsDir = (LPCWSTR)wStr.c_str();
    DWORD dwWaitStatus;
    HANDLE dwChangeHandle;
    dwChangeHandle = FindFirstChangeNotification(
        lpcwsDir,
        FALSE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);

    while (TRUE)
    {
        // returns multiple times before and after new file appears!!
        dwWaitStatus = WaitForSingleObject(dwChangeHandle, INFINITE);
        switch(dwWaitStatus)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            GetCurrentFilesInDir(sDir, vsNewFileList);
            std::string sNewFileName = FindNewFile(vsNewFileList, vsOldFileList);
            std::cout << sNewFileName << "\n";
            GetCurrentFilesInDir(sDir, vsOldFileList);
            FindNextChangeNotification(dwChangeHandle);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I save a new file in `C:\foo` (for instance, using Notepad++ to "Save As" an open `.txt` file in `C:\foo`), the call to `WaitForSingleObject()` in the `while` loop will return 0 multiple times. Since my `FindNewFile()` method returns an empty string if there is no new file in the directory, I will get output like:

```
a.txt
```

or:

```
b.txt
```

Or even:

```
c.txt

c.txt
```

Can someone explain what I am missing here?

Comment: `std::wstring(sDir.begin(), sDir.end())` works for ASCII characters only. I don't see you enforcing this restriction in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `FindNextChangeNotification` can not tell you what actually happened, and the operation of the file may involve multiple changes.

You can try to use [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) and here is a sample:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
wstring getname(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* tmp)
{
    wstring s = L"";
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp->FileNameLength / 2; i++)
        s += tmp->FileName[i];
    return s;
}
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    HANDLE hDir;
    char notify[1024];
    DWORD cbBytes;
    LPTSTR path;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* pnotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)notify;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* tmp;
    //    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH+1));
    path = (LPTSTR)L"D:\\test";
    hDir = CreateFile(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ |
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE |
        FILE_SHARE_DELETE, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS |
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
    wcout << L"===CreateFile complete===" << endl;
    if (hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wcout << L"invalid handle value" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION buffer[1024];
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* pbuffer;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        wcout << L"waiting..." << endl;
        WaitForSingleObject(hDir, INFINITE);
        if (ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir, &buffer, sizeof(buffer),
            TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
            &cbBytes, NULL, NULL))
        {
            pbuffer = buffer;
            do {
                tmp = pbuffer;
                switch (tmp->Action)
                {
                case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
                    wcout << L"Directory/File added - " << getname(tmp) << endl;
                    break;
                case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
                    wcout << L"Directory/File removed - " << getname(tmp) << endl;
                    break;
                case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
                    wcout << L"Directory/File modfied - " << getname(tmp) << endl;
                    break;
                case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME:
                    wcout << L"Directory/File old name - " << getname(tmp) << endl;
                    break;
                case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME:
                    wcout << L"Directory/File new name - " << getname(tmp) << endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    wcout << L"unknown action\n" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                pbuffer += pbuffer->NextEntryOffset;
            } while (pbuffer->NextEntryOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            wcout << "readChangesW failed  now return" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

When you do the Save As operation, you will find:

[image]

Therefore, multiple file operations were triggered when actually saving as, and you also performed multiple comparisons when processing new file comparisons, so empty characters were output.

More reference: [FindFirstChangeNotification is notifying about changes twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865232/findfirstchangenotification-is-notifying-about-changes-twice)